# Add a "Support the Economics.SE beta" banner in your "About me"

Tags: discussion, advertising

First of all, congratulation to everyone who worked to have the private beta move public!

If you are active on other SE webiste, an effective way to advertise Economics.SE might be to add a little banner to the "About me" section of your SE profile.

Here are two templates, feel free to add more via answers :

1)

============================

Support the [Economics.SE beta](http://economics.stackexchange.com).

============================

2)

[http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/61732.png](http://economics.stackexchange.com)

$\\$

A good way to complement the banner might be to [follow @EnergyNumbers and add a short list a of questions that you like](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/energynumbers).

Hopefully, that will contribute to help us move toward graduation.

Comment: And where do we get this banner?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos : I added some templates (maybe my use of the word "banner" was a little bit exaggerated...)

Comment: PS: you can use the "edit" function to copy the code associated with the banners.

Comment: Ok done, thanks.

Comment: And I was wondering "how are the number of days updated?" Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure it does. My hope was that the initial picture I uploaded would be updated on a daily basis while keeping the same URL. When I realized it was not the case, I tried another URL. A side effect was the "manual" update in the number of days. Yet, even with this new URL, I have little hope that the picture be updated without a change in the URL. If any one finds a trick, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Well it seems like I was too pessimistic :)

Comment: Indeed this url updates the days automatically.